# facebook->getuser() return null with php3.2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is a strange problem:
In a php script facebook->getUser(); return null also if the user is logged in...

```
// include PHP-SDK 3.2.3
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => '$AppId',
   'secret' => '$secret',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

the function is called before any html layout.
Next, in the body, I call the JS-SDK 2.0, here the user is recognised becouse I see my Like checked in the iframe likes box count, furthemore if I check/uncheck the likes on the facebook page the action is reported in the iframe layout.

the iframe likes box is called with:

```
echo "<iframe src=\"//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href="."$fb_id[link]"."&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=85&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;font&amp;force_wall=false\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:85px; height:65px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>"
```

$fb_id is the page array called by
     $fb_id = $facebook->api($FB_pid);
located just after the getuser call

Looks like the JS-SDK and the PHP-SDK don't share their data.

any tips?

Comment: I would suggest that you use SDK v4 and FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper

Comment: I'm upgrading a large apps to Auth 2.0 using the test app, I have not time enough at moment to migrate to 4.0.